# how to create date object which starts with zero for validating the date the partial datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

creating a date object with zero value to indicate the null object in partial date picker. for validation purpose zero value is need in the partial datepicker

```
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(0);
  alert(d);
```

is that possible to create date object with zero value ?

Comment: What is the purpose ? If you want the timestamp 0, you can do `var d = new Date(0);`

Comment: its useful for validation in partial date picker. from a date 15-09-2015. if  select  month then the selected value must be 00-09-0000. which should be valide date object.

Comment: when i try this var d = new Date(0); it shows date which system created.

Comment: @Pierre-Alexandre Moller thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "zero value."

You can do this:

```
var d = new Date(0);
```

...which creates a `Date` representing January 1st 1970 at midnight, UTC. Its time value is `0`, but the time value is an offset from "The Epoch," and so it represents a real date.

If you want a `Date` that doesn't actually represent a specific date, you can use `NaN` as the time value:

```
var d = new Date(NaN);
```

All of the `getXyz` methods (`getFullYear`, etc.) will return `NaN`, and `toString` will return `"Invalid Date"`.

Whether that works for your use case depends on your datepicker.